# criar barra de menu no topo fixa

Tags: html, css

Queria saber como faço para criar uma barra de menu fixa no topo, ao lado de um menu lateral, que quando rolar a div do conteudo tanto o menu lateral quando o do topo continuem fixos. Segue o html e css de modelo.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

body{
   background-color: #f3f5f9;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #363636;
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
 
.wrapper .sidebar .social_media{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .social_media a{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  background: #594f8d;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #bdb8d7;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 21px;
  background: #4169E1;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-height: 500px){
  .social_media{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu-principal.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>Logo</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Ativos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i>Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i>Map</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <div class="social_media">
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="header">Welcome!! Have a nice day.</div>  
        <div class="info">
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual, de preferência com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara tem várias formas de fazer a mais prática é colocar `positin:fixed` na sidebar, isso já deixa ela fixa na rolagem.

Depois na navbar vc coloca `position:sticky` e `top:0` para ela ficar fixa na rolagem, basicamente é isso. Tb tem que dar um `padding-top: 60px;` na classe `.info` para o conteúdo não ficar por baixo da `navbar`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```css
  @charset "UTF-8";

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

body{
   background-color: #f3f5f9;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #363636;
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
 
.wrapper .sidebar .social_media{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .social_media a{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  background: #594f8d;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #bdb8d7;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 21px;
  background: #4169E1;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-height: 500px){
  .social_media{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>Logo</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Ativos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i>Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i>Map</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <div class="social_media">
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="header">Welcome!! Have a nice day.</div>  
        <div class="info">
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito cara, muito obrigado pela explicação, sou novo com programação web e entendo muito pouco de css,mas eu necessito aprender para desenvolver um projeto pra facul, aproveitando o post você sabe como posso me aperfeiçoar em css, alguma fonte boa pra estudos..

Comment: @Rickkdinho cara se a resposta resolveu seu problema considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔️ abaixo das setinhas do lado da minha resposta, assim ela não fica aberta mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. Estude sobre `position` vai te ajudar muito!

Comment: Feito amigo, tbm não sabia da setinha, sou novo aqui tbm hehe, vlws!!!

Comment: @Rickkdinho sem problemas vlw a força